# is routes.php file in laravel 5.5 doesn't exists

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have search routes.php file in laravel 5.5 but i'm not find it. 
Is routes.php file in laravel 5.5.32 doesn't exists ?. 
Sorry i am a newbie in laravel.

Comment: In my Laravel 5.5.14 you'll find inside routes folder. web.php

Answer (score 2):

Since 5.3, It's `web.php` inside the **routes** folder.

Comment: always read changelog :D there were so many breaking changes from < 5.2 to 5.3